# Configure IIS 10 for ODBC Logging

Tags: odbc, windows-server-2016, iis-10

I created database, table, and DSN for ODBC logging on windows server 2016 but I don't know how to configure IIS to use ODBC logging. 
when I select Log File format as “Custom” in the IIS manager, it doesn’t give me options to configure ODBC logging in the UI. Instead, it just gives me an alert saying it cannot be configured through IIS manager which you already know.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/odbclogging

Comment: I look at this link and also http://nirav.extreme-advice.com/2013/07/29/configure-iis-8-0-log-to-sql-server/
but when I want to config APPCMD I get this error:
unknown config section "system.webServer/odbcLogging /dataSource:”IISLogs” /commit:apphost".

Comment: Clearly you should not rely on IIS Manager, but modify the config file or use `appcmd`.